# Generate pcapng files in a C++ program

Tags: c++, pcap-ng

I have a C++ program that is able to generate `pcap` files. However, I would like to embed additional information in the recorded frames, and I understand that the newer format `pcapng` allows adding arbitrary comments to frames, which I would like to take advantage of. I also understand that `libwiretap` is able to generate `pcapng` files, but I find no reference, tutorials or examples. My needs are very simple: I just have to open a `pcapng` file, every now and then dump a packet into it and then close it in the end. Do you have any useful references on where to start?

Answer (score 2):

After some trial-and-error and reading header files, I came up with this test snippet:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wiretap/wtap.h>

int main() {

  int err;
  wtap_dumper *dumper = wtap_dump_open_ng("test.pcapng", WTAP_FILE_TYPE_SUBTYPE_PCAPNG, WTAP_ENCAP_ETHERNET, 65535, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, &err);

  char *packet = "helloworld";
  char *err_info;
  struct wtap_pkthdr header;
  wtap_phdr_init(&header);
  header.caplen = strlen(packet);
  header.len = strlen(packet);
  gettimeofday(&header.ts, NULL);
  header.opt_comment = "how are you?";
  wtap_dump(dumper, &header, packet, &err, &err_info);
  wtap_phdr_cleanup(&header);

  wtap_dump_close(dumper, &err);

  return 0;

}
```

I don't think it is good code, but is just works for me (of course it generates invalid packets). Also, there is no error checking at the moment.

Compile with:

```
gcc -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs wireshark` -lwiretap test.c
```